# Objective C : how to get the list of possible values returned by [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode]?

Tags: ios, macos, localization, internationalization

I use :

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode];
```

to determine the user language.

Where can I get the full list of the possible returned values (e.g. "fr"), and corresponding language (e.g. "french").

Thanks !

Comment: Look up [ISO-3166](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm)

Comment: Thanks but it is a list of countries, not a list of languages. For example, the method will return "pt" for a brazilian and not "br".

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways you can go.

1. Iterate over `Locale.isoLanguageCodes` and extract all 2-letter codes:

```swift
    for languageCode in Locale.isoLanguageCodes {
        print(languageCode) // or print(languageCode.prefix(2))
    }
```

2. Iterate over `Locale.availableIdentifiers` and execute `Locale.components(fromIdentifier:_)` on every item.

```swift
for identifier in Locale.availableIdentifiers {
    let components = Locale.components(fromIdentifier: identifier)
    // ...
 }
```

A full list is standardized in [ISO-639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) list.

Comment: Thanks but are all these languages available on iOS ?